# Pausing multiple youtube Iframe videos on each slideshow transition

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, flexslider

I am new to the YouTube Iframe API and am trying to pause several embedded Iframe videos that are in a slideshow (jQuery flexslider plugin) when a user moves to a different slide. If the player isn't paused, the video continues to play and, since there will be  multiple videos in the slide show, I need each one to pause when a new slide is revealed. The Iframes are not inserted via the API, but are already present in the html due to the CMS I am using.

I have read through the API reference and several answers I found on here, but am having trouble figuring out how to pause any/every Iframe video when a user transitions to a new slide.

In my latest attempt, as seen in the code below, I have tried to pause the Iframes whenever a link is clicked, since the only links on the page will be for navigating to the next and previous slides. I also have tried to pause all videos on a slide transition event provided via the flexslider API, but with no success.

```
var players = {}; //players storage object
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
    $('iframe[id]').each(function(){
        var identifier = this.id;
        var frameID = getFrameID(identifier);
        if (frameID) { // if iframe exists
            players[frameID] = new YT.Player(frameID, {
                events: {
                    "onStateChange" : createYTEvent(frameID, identifier)
                }
            });            
        }
    });
}

//returns a function to enable  multiple events
function createYTEvent(frameID, identifier){
    return function (event){
        var player = players[frameID]; //set player reference
        var done = false;

        $('a').click(function(){

            player.pauseVideo();
            return false;

        });        
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my English, I'm French, but I got the same problem recently, and maybe I thought that I could help you or another person in the future.

The difference with you is that I only used 1 player loading a list of 4 videos, and not 4 players.

**There is my HTML:**

```
<div id='videos'>
    <div id="player">
        <!-- the iframe drectly write in the html, with a list of videos (4 in the example) -->
        <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/youtubeVideoId1?playlist=youtubeVideoId2,youtubeVideoId3,youtubeVideoId4&version=3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
        <!-- below, the buttons for switching the 4 videos -->
        <span id='pagination'>
            <a onclick='video_slide(0);' id='puce1'></a>
            <a onclick='video_slide(1);' id='puce2'></a>
            <a onclick='video_slide(2);' id='puce3'></a>
            <a onclick='video_slide(3);' id='puce4'></a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**and my Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // call the youtube API
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // init the player
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            events: {
                // the function "onPlayerStateChange is call when the player load, 
                   play, pause or stop a video
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        // if a new video is buffering (the event.data is -1 when buffering, 
           1 when playing, 2 when paused ...)
        if (event.data == -1) {
            // it mean that the player pass at the next video, 
               so we call the bellow function to turn on the corresponding button
            getTheRightPuce();
        }
    }
    // I add a function to recognize the current video playing, 
       and turn on the right button automatically when at the end of a video, 
       the player pass on the next one
    function getTheRightPuce(){
        var vidIndex = player.getPlaylistIndex();

        $("#pagination a").css('backgroundColor','#000000');

        if (vidIndex==0){$("#puce1").css('backgroundColor','red');}
        else if (vidIndex==1){$("#puce2").css('backgroundColor','red');}
        else if (vidIndex==2){$("#puce3").css('backgroundColor','red');}
        else if (vidIndex==3){$("#puce4").css('backgroundColor','red');}
    }

    // the function called by the buttons, change the current video 
       on the player and turn on the corresponding button, 
       the parameter is the index of the video in the play-list 
       (0 for the first, 1 for second...)
    function video_slide(sld){

        player.playVideoAt(sld);

        $("#videos").css('display','none');
        $("#pagination a").css('backgroundColor','#000000');
        $("#videos").fadeIn(500);
        if (sld==0){$("#puce1").css('backgroundColor','red');}
        else if (sld==1){$("#puce2").css('backgroundColor','red');}
        else if (sld==2){$("#puce3").css('backgroundColor','red');}
        else if (sld==3){$("#puce4").css('backgroundColor','red');}
    }
</script>
```

I tried to make it as clearer as possible.

I hope this will help you or someone else :)